# Form emailing on browser load

Tags: php, email, redirect, load

The form I have created below emails the input data in a CSV file.
The problem I am having is every time the browser loads the page it sends a blank version of the CSV file, and
once the form is submitted I want it to redirect to a "thank you" page. How can I accomplish this?

The PHP I use before the HTML form is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) {
}

$email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
$firstName=$_REQUEST['firstName']; 
$lastName=$_REQUEST['lastName']; 


$to = "Ali@ebig.co.uk"; 
 $subject = "New application submission"; 


 $message = "". 
 "Email: $email" . "\n" . 
 "First Name: $firstName" . "\n" . 
 "Last Name: $lastName";


//The Attachment    
$varTitle = $_POST['formTitle'];    
$varForname = $_POST['formForname'];
$varMiddlename = $_POST['formMiddlename'];
$varSurname = $_POST['formSurname'];
$varKnownas = $_POST['formKnownas'];
$varAdressline1 = $_POST['formAdressline1'];
$varAdressline2 = $_POST['formAdressline2'];
$varAdressline3 = $_POST['formAdressline3'];
$varAdressline4 = $_POST['formAdressline4'];
$varAdressline5 = $_POST['formAdressline5'];
$varPostcode = $_POST['formPostcode'];
$varTelephone = $_POST['formTelephone'];
$varMobile = $_POST['formMobile'];
$varEmail = $_POST['formEmail'];
$varApproval = $_POST['formApproval'];
$varothersurname = $_POST['formothersurname'];
$varsex = $_POST['formsex'];
$varninumber = $_POST['formninumber'];
$varjobtitle = $_POST['formjobtitle'];
$vardates = $_POST['formdates'];
$varresponsibilities = $_POST['formresponsibilities'];
$varjobtitle2 = $_POST['formjobtitle2'];
$vardates2 = $_POST['formdates2'];
$varresponsibilities2 = $_POST['formresponsibilities2'];
$varjobtitle3 = $_POST['formjobtitle3'];
$vardates3 = $_POST['formdates3'];
$varresponsibilities3 = $_POST['formresponsibilities3'];
$varwebsite = $_POST['formwebsite'];
$vartshirt = $_POST['formtshirt'];
$vardietary = $_POST['formdietary'];
$varpc = $_POST['formpc'];
$varmac = $_POST['formmac'];
$varlaptop = $_POST['formlaptop'];
$vardongle = $_POST['formdongle'];
$varediting = $_POST['formediting'];
$varsocial = $_POST['formsocial'];
$varphotography = $_POST['formphotography'];
$varfilming = $_POST['formfilming'];
$vartraining = $_POST['formtraining'];
$varexhibition = $_POST['formexhibition'];
$varspecial = $_POST['formspecial'];
$varhobbies = $_POST['formhobbies'];
$varphotography = $_POST['formphotography'];
$varfilming = $_POST['formfilming'];
$vartraining = $_POST['formtraining'];
$varexcel = $_POST['formexcel'];
$varbigpicture = $_POST['formbigpicture'];
$varcriminal = $_POST['formcriminal'];

$cr = "\n"; 
$data = "$varTitle" . ',' . "$varForname" . ',' . "$varMiddlename" . ',\\other variables.


$attachments[] = Array( 
  'data' => $data, 
  'name' => 'application.csv', 
  'type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel' 
); 


//Generate a boundary string 

$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 


//Add the headers for a file attachment 


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" . 
       "From: {$from}\n" . 
         "Cc: davidkirrage@gmail.com\n". 
       "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . 
       " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 


//Add a multipart boundary above the plain message 


$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
      "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . 
      "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
      $text . "\n\n"; 


//Add sttachments 

foreach($attachments as $attachment){ 
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($attachment['data'])); 
$name = $attachment['name']; 
$type = $attachment['type']; 




$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . 
          "Content-Type: {$type};\n" . 
          " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .               
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . 
          $data . "\n\n" ; 


$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n"; 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 


}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your line at the top, which checks to see if the page is a form submit, does not expand for the entire function.

You currently have:

```
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) {
}
```

However the closing bracket } should be all the way at the bottom, right before the ?>.  As it stands now, your code is doing a check to see if there was a form submit, and if so it's executing nothing, since there is no code within those brackets.  After that is completed it automatically begins running through all of your other code, regardless if it was a form submit or not.

If you're wanting the page to redirect, place the below code right before the newly moved closing bracket:

```
header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.php');
```

Comment: the header php code for redirecting doesn't work